# Is there a way to enforce execution order of test classes in Junit4(5)

Tags: spring-boot, junit, junit5, spring-boot-test

I am writing integration tests in a SpringBootApp with Junit5. It is a must for me to follow a execution order of REST Api calls. In one test class it is ok to use @TestMethodOrder from jUnit5 or another approach for test execution ordering in a class. My question is regard execution test classes in specific order. I found an open issue on the topic in the Junit repo https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1948 . It's not resolved. Is there a way to achieve this? I have think of @Categories introduced from Junit5 but it will be too hacky approach, it is not an option.